# How to pass ID of setInterval() to anonymous funtion

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval, anonymous

I'm looking to pass the handler of `setInterval()` to the internal function.

For example:

```
var id = setInterval(myfunction, "100000");
```

I'm looking to pass `id` to `myfunction`

I tried

```
setInterval(myfunciton(e), "10000");
```

but it didn't pass the variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood you, you can't pass a parameter that isn't even defined yet...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The id doesn't exist when you call `setInterval`, but it does exist by the time that the callback is called.

You would need to wrap the call in a function that uses the id in a call:

```
var id = setInterval(function(){
  myfunction(id);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused -- how can you pass `id` to the function if it hasn't been declared as a variable yet?

Comment: @SterlingArcher By the time the function is called, `id` has existed for 10 seconds.

Comment: This looks like it should work, however, it just errors: id is not defined.

Comment: Scratch that last comment, I needed to empty my cache for the changes to load.

Answer (score 1):

If you include the variable in the callback as it's passed in to setInterval, the callback is immediately executing with that argument.

What you need to do is create a closure:

```
setInterval(function() {
  myFunction(e);
}, 10000);
```

Also, the interval should be an integer, not a string.